# Can I download Postman binaries and run it without installing?

Tags: windows, postman

Can I use Postman on Windows without installation?

I'd like to just download a zip file, unpack and run it without installation.

I know that there is a web version of Postman, but my intention is to use it as one application on Windows.

Thanks